# jQuery: Can't get tooltip plugin to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tooltip

I'm trying to use this tooltip plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/. I can't seem to get it to work.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/JQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.json-2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js-lib/jquery.bgiframe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js-lib/jquery.delegate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js-lib/jquery.dimensions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.tooltip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/sprintf.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/clientside.js"></script>
</head>
```

I try it out in a simple example:

**clientside.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#set1 *").tooltip();
});
```

The target html:

```
   <div id="set1">
                <p id="welcome">Welcome. What is your email?</p>
                <form id="form-username-form" action="api/user_of_email" method="get">
                    <p>
                    <label for="form-username">Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="form-username" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="form-submit" />
                    </p>
                </form>
                <p id="msg-user-accepted"></p>
            </div>
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `title` attribute on your elements to get the tooltip, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="form-username" title="My Tooltip" />
```

[You can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbZbw/)

Also make sure you're including [the CSS file](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/jquery.tooltip.css), or have CSS of your own to style the tooltip, the default stylesheet the tooltip plugin includes is:

```
#tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3000;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 5px;
    opacity: 0.85;
}
#tooltip h3, #tooltip div { margin: 0; }
```